# Setting up ReactiveUI.Mobile

Tags: mvvm, routes, windows-runtime, reactiveui

In the following documentation, https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/docs/docs/basics/routing.md

It states that by setting up ReactiveUI.Mobile, you will be able to achieve correct handling of the back button for free. I've tried to look around for documentation but can't seem to find any.

Could someone point me to a suitable link / sample that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It states that by setting up ReactiveUI.Mobile, you will be able to achieve correct handling of the back button for free. I've tried to look around for documentation but can't seem to find any.

Setting up RxUI.Mobile is super platform-dependent, and you only get a free back button on WP8 Silverlight apps. I'd stick with just using routing (or avoiding routing altogether) for now. RxUI.Mobile will probably change quite a bit in 6.0 (it's my least favorite part of the framework at the moment).